# root password works for "su", but not for sudo

Tags: password, root, reset

I forgot my root password and later reset it by modifying the grub boot loader script: "ro" to "rw init=/bin/bash". After that, "Ctrl+X" brought me to a root environment where I created my new root password.

This new password enables me to enter the root environment (# instead $) where I can do everything that requires "sudo". However, this password couldn't work when I try to do the command "sudo apt-get ...".

If the password used by "sudo" should be the user's password, how could I create a new one if I have already logged into the system? I simply forgot this password. I could log into the system because the system is set without a login required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: root user password and your user password (when you do sudo apt .. you use your user not root user) are 2 different things. For sudo apt .. you use your regular user password (assuming that user is in sudoers group).

Comment: I have logged into the system, but I forgot my user password

Comment: If you are logged as root user you can change your regular users password with: passwd <YOUR USERNAME>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)